# Add "Add new" item to ComboBox

Tags: wpf, model, combobox

Ok, this sounds trivial even to me, but I'm not able to find an answer to this.
I have a normal `ComboBox`, which works perfectly.

What I would like to do is add an `element` *(as the last item of the `drop-down list`)* which is nothing but a *Add new* `label`; when this item is selected, I want to open a window which allows me to define the properties of the `element` I'm adding.

Right now I have the following:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="myCombo"
    SelectedValue="{Binding Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
    ItemsSource="{Binding Definitions}" 
    SelectedValuePath="Name"
    DisplayMemberPath="Name"
    SelectionChanged="CheckToAdd" />
```

And the `CheckToAdd` function is like this:

```
private void CheckToAdd(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (((myViewModel)e.AddedItems[0]).Name.Value.Equals("Add new"))
    {
        AddNewItem(sender, null);
    }
}
```

What I do is have a *dummy* `element` in my `Definitions` which has *Add new* as `Name`. Using this approach makes all working, but it's ugly IMO *(because the problem is just a `view` thing, so I don't think it's correct to mess with the `VM or the Model`)*.

Anyone has a better idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no equivalent of ASP.NET's `AppendDataBoundItems` for WPF. You may be able to get somewhere by modifying the ControlTemplate, or you could simplify your current approach tp make it more readable. Something like:

```
private void CheckToAdd(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e) {
    if (cbo.SelectedIndex == Definitions.Count()) {
        AddNewItem(sender, null);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep it in my way, and making it more readable with your suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this really belongs in a comment to the accepted answer, but I have insufficient rep.

Could you elaborate on:

1. How to ensure `element` with `name` "Add new" stays at the bottom.
2. How to wrap the `Collection` from the Model in the ViewModel while adding the dummy item.

Answer (score -2):

if u follow binding in wpf u have to inset item in collection(here Definitions) and make this collection notify(using INotifyPropertyChanged) then automatically your ComboBox is update when new item is inserted it's not only one way to do to this but it's best practices

see following link to that's defind how to implement INotifyPropertyChanged

http://wpftutorial.net/INotifyPropertyChanged.html

Comment: My collection is already working as expected (with notification and all that stuff); what I need is a way to add a custom entry just to the `ComboBox`'s drop-down list, without having it added to the `ItemsSource`, which would imply having it in my VM (in general), and in my Model (in my case, due to other necessities of my program). Thanks, anyway :)